# Where does the Python shell from `run-python` store its input history?

Tags: python, comint, history-variables

As in the question title, I want to know where the inferior Python shell stores its command history (the history you cycle through through with the up arrow).

I've been searching high and low. I'm trying to make this variable persistent using `savehist-additional-variables`, but I can't find the variable. I've looked for all variables containing history, ring, command, input, etc, and none of them have been it. The few I thought might be it all were valued nil despite my having stuff in my command history that I could cycle through.

Answer (score 1):

The inferior Python shell uses comint for managing inputs. The variable you're looking for is most likely `comint-input-ring`. Just bear in mind that it's buffer-local.

Comment: Ohhhhhhh that probably explains it. I was looking at that variable, but I thought it wasn't it because it evaluated to nil.

Comment: Is there an effective way to preserve the state of a buffer-local variable so that it will be set in the next `*Python*`Buffer? I don't want to use any kind of full Bowen session management.

Comment: I suppose I could do it with advice or a repeating timer, but I'd rather use something built-in if possible.

Comment: Oh I thin I'm being silly. When I'm at my computer I'll try the obvious thing of just putting it in the list. I was thinking I already did that but I think it was another variable I tried that on come to think of it.

Comment: Yep, that should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

This does not really answer your question, but using `ipython` as the python shell remembers history out-of-the-box:

```
(setq python-shell-interpreter "ipython")
```

You might need to add to fix some `ipython` weirdness:

```
(setq python-shell-interpreter-args "--simple-prompt -i")
```